# Raspberry Pi and CUPS with OKI C3200

Tags: printing, cups

I'm trying to use my Raspberry Pi (`raspberrypi 3.10.25+`) as an print server gateway to my OKI C3200.
I have successfully installed `CUPS 1.5.3` and my printer was detected immediately, so the installation/setup was not a problem.
This is how it looks like now (it is in German though):

[image: cups1]

After successfully adding the printer in windows 7, I get the following error message when trying to print something:

[image: cups2]

...which basically translates to:

```
"Could not connect printer to LPR port"
```

Printing a test page via CUPS does not work either. 
The funny thing is, I can print documents from my iPhone 4 without a problem, so it is possible to use the OKI C3200 as a network printer.
Now, I am not really sure if this problem is because I am missing something with the CUPS configuration or if the cause lays somewhere completely different, so if a moderator thinks this topic is wrong here, feel free to edit/move/delete it.
Maybe someone else encountered this error message and knows how to do fix this?

Comment: I remember getting a OKI to work by sharing the cups printer via Samba to Windows hosts, maybe you don't mind trying the same

Comment: @Gotschi Nice idea, unfortunately the documents in queue are being stuck with the status `spooling`. Any idea where this comes from?

Answer (score 2):

Something I've noticed here with a C3200N is that nothing will print from windows until I've logged into the printer one time.

All I've had to do is open a cmd window
telnet to the IP address of the printer 
login as root
exit out of the telnet session 
close the cmd window

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but I will add that, rather than use Samba I have had the most success with using the Bonjour Printer Wizard [Bonjour Print Services](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL999?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) on my Windows machines to print to a RPi based CUPS server (DYMO LabelWriter 400 and Kyocera FS-1010).  Also Bonjour is great for hostname resolution when the pi is headless.

Anyway, using Bonjour the port is a 'Internet Port' in the windows printer properties referring to port 631 (CUPS), rather than LPR on 515 - perhaps you aren't using the IPP protocol.  I understand CUPS supports LPR but just sayin'